# Download Scenario validation in openfin with webdriverio

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, openfin

I  have a UI automation scenario, where I need to perform the export to excel operation and save the file from UI. This operation, I need to do in openfin browser. How can we set preferences in openfin browser so that it will automatically save downloaded files to a preferred location?

Note: Framework is based in webdriverio and javascript/Typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised the same query to openfin team. Below is their response:

Hi,

For security purposes, OpenFin does not allow to automatically save a file to a specific folder. The user will always be presented with a save as dialog.
If you’re a pro and want to get serious about support, you may be interested in an Enterprise License. It offers Professional support through a production SLA fit for financial web applications. You can apply for a 30-day support trail via or website openfin.co.

Hope this information will help someone who is looking for the same.